# How to change a date type to short date

Tags: excel, date, formatting, excel-formula, data-manipulation

How would you change this date type `Monday, 31, August2015 at 6:08 AM` to short date in Excel `31/08/2015` ?

Currently I use Text to Columns on the top date, find and replace to remove the comma on `31,`. Then use a combination of `=text(1,"00")` and `=month(A1&1` to format the numbers correctly and finally =concatenation() to join them all together.

This is time consuming and concatenated dates are in a different format to short date formats. When uploading data the software will see them as such.

I'm hoping there is a really easy way of doing this to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a long formula, but it works. Before using it make sure you set the Number Formatting for the formula cell to the short date that you want.

Assuming that your awkward date is in cell A1, enter this formula in another cell:

```
=DATEVALUE(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99),1,2),",","")) & " " & MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",2))+1,3) & " " & MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",3))-4,4))
```

Comment: This is awesome, wouldn't have guessed that :) - Works well